# Directory.CreateDirectory does not create a folder

Tags: c#, .net, path, directory, filepath

I am trying to create a new directory using `Directory.CreateDirectory()`, but I am unable to understand why it does not create a new directory when I use the following code.

```
var directory = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "Status" + "-" + "Test" + Guid.NewGuid() + "\\");
Directory.CreateDirectory(directory);
```

But when I manually feed the file path it creates the directory (works well).

```
Directory.CreateDirectory(@"F:\Code\Help\");
```

Am I doing it wrong?

Any comments or feedback is greatly appreciated. TIA.

Comment: Sorry that was the wrong string I pasted `"F:\\Code\\Help\\Status-Test-4cb61c98-bf52-42de-bb1e-c827c4a97e01"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code per-se

My suspicion is you **are** creating a directory (somewhere)

```
try
{
   var directory = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, $@"Status-Test{Guid.NewGuid()}");
   Console.WriteLine(directory);

   var di = Directory.CreateDirectory(directory);

   Console.WriteLine($"The directory was created successfully at {Directory.GetCreationTime(directory)}.");
   Console.WriteLine($"==> { di.FullName}");
}
catch (Exception e)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Oh NOES!: {0}", e);
}
```

[Environment.CurrentDirectory Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.currentdirectory(v=vs.110).aspx)

> By definition, if this process starts in the root directory of a local
>   or network drive, the value of this property is the drive name
>   followed by a trailing slash (for example, "C:\"). If this process
>   starts in a subdirectory, the value of this property is the drive and
>   subdirectory path, without a trailing slash (for example,
>   "C:\mySubDirectory").